# docker pull returning image not found

Tags: docker

```
docker pull localhost:21518/master:latest
```

Getting following response:

> Trying to pull repository localhost:21518/master ...
>   Pulling repository localhost:21518/master
>   Error: image master:latest not found

Whereas `docker images` returns

```
REPOSITORY                           TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
localhost:21518/master     latest              e9f29fbf9931        6 hours ago         703 MB
```

Why image is not getting pulled?

Comment: try tagging the image via docker tag command to a simpler name and then try to pull using the new name


docker tag localhost:21518/master:latest master:latest

Comment: It’s not on the “remote” server, possibly because you never `docker push`ed it.

Comment: There is no remote server here. The repository is on localhost only.

Comment: Because the name is sort of wrong :) you might use some other name if you are using a Docker registry. If it is just for you, you can just call it myimage:1.0.0, if you will have to add it to an external registry then you will use a proper DNS / IP address and not localhost.

Comment: Are you running a registry server on your local host? Include the steps you've taken to do that. Then, have you first pushed your image to that registry server? Show that output in your question too.

Comment: I got it thanks everyone. The image was not pushed on local repository. I thought docker images shows repository list.

Answer (score 0):

`docker images` shows the list of cached images and not repository images. I got confused that docker images showing images from repository as repository is also running on local machine.
Needed to do `docker push` to get image in repository.